# NSView not fire keyEvent

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nsevent

I have made a custom `NSView` and have implemented the `keyDown:` method. However, when I press keys the method is never called. How can I receive those event ? I had override `keyDown:` method in my custom view

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString *theUpArrow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",NSUpArrowFunctionKey];
    NSLog(@"get key : %@",theUpArrow);
}
```

and also create method in subclass of `NSView` like

```
 - (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder
 {
     return YES;
 }

 - (BOOL) becomeFirstResponder
 {
     return YES;
 }

 - (BOOL) resignFirstResponder
 {
     return YES;
 }
```

also I called method there of above method when `initWithFrame:` but not getting `keyEvent:` on this view 
I am new in mac developing i was read most doc for that but still helpless.
 So please correct my mistake if any and giving me some hint to how i will get keydown event on my custom view.

Comment: Are you sure you get into `becomeFirstResponder`? Did you try to dump the responder chain?

Comment: @Andriy yes i get in to becomeFirstResponder, i don't have idea to responder chain

Comment: does your view has focus?

Comment: @Volker my view has focus

Comment: i was add this view as a subview in TableviewCell class.

Comment: that might cause this - events may get stolen by the table view